# Invalid Parameter Number when uploading an image

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a form that will allow a user to input information, and then upload an image to go with that information. When all of the information has been entered and an image attached, if I press the submit button I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.

However the image is uploaded anyway and nothing is actually inserted into the database

Before submission, I also get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: image in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\authTest\adminNewProperty.php on line 5

This is the code for the form: (adminNewProperty.php)

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
//var_dump($_FILES);
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//Checks if the create new activity button was clicked, if it was, the entered data will be used to create a new activity 
if(isset($_POST['button_CreateProperty']))
{
    $check                              = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    $property_title                 = $_POST['title'];
    $property_address               = $_POST['address'];
    $property_description       = $_POST['description'];
    $property_rent                  = $_POST['rent'];
    $property_reference         = $_POST['reference'];
    $property_image             = $_FILES['image']['name'];

   //Error handling
   //Checks if the activity name is empty, if it is, produce an error
   if(strlen($property_title)=="") 
   {
        $error[] = "Please enter a title for this property"; 
   }

   //Checks if the activity date is empty, if it is, produce an error
   if($property_address=="") 
   {
        $error[] = "Please enter the address for this property"; 
   } 
   //Checks if the activity start time is empty, if it is, throw an error
   if($property_description=="") 
   {
        $error[] = "Please enter a description of this property";
   } 

   //Checks if the activity end time is empty, if it is, throw an error
   if($property_rent=="")
   {
        $error[] = "Please enter a description of the property";
   } 

   //Checks if the activity description is empty
   if($property_reference=="") 
   {
        $error[] = "Please enter a reference for this property";
   }

         //IMAGE UPLOAD
    if($check !== false) 
    {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }


// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) 
{
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 900000) 
{
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
{
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) 
{
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else 
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

   if (empty($error))
   {
      try
      {
         $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM property WHERE property_reference=:reference");
         $stmt->execute(array(':reference'=>$property_reference));
         $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

         if($row['reference']==$property_reference) 
         {
            $error[] = "There is already a property with this reference!";
         }
         else
         {
             //if all entered data successfully validates, the property is created and the user is taken to the index
            if(true === $property->new_property($property_title, $property_address, $property_description, $property_rent, $property_reference, $property_image)) 
            {
                $user->redirect('properties.php');
            }
         }
     }
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
     }
  } 
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Guardian</title>
    <!--Bootstrap 4 CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MIwDKRSSImVFAZCVLtU0LMDdON6KVCrZHyVQQj6e8wIEJkW4tvwqXrbMIya1vriY" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Bootstrap 4 JS-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ux8v3A6CPtOTqOzMKiuo3d/DomGaaClxFYdCu2HPMBEkf6x2xiDyJ7gkXU0MWwaD" crossorigin="anonymous">  </script>
    <!--Custom Styling-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<h1> New Property Listing </h1>
<?php echo implode('</br>', (array)$error) ?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Property Title:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title of the Property" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $property_title;}?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="rent">Property Address:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address for the property" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $property_address;}?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Property Description:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description of the property" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $property_description;}?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="reference">Property Rent:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rent" name="rent" placeholder="Monthly rent for this property" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $property_rent;}?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="reference">Property Reference:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Unique identifier for this property" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $property_reference;}?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Upload an Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" value="Upload Image">
    <p class="help-block">Upload an image to be used with this property listing</p>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="button_CreateProperty">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

also, this is the class I am using:

```
   <?php
    class Property
    {

        private $db;
        private $error;

        //Create property class on execute, using database connection (DB_Con) in dbconfig.php
        function __construct($DB_con)
        {
          $this->db = $DB_con;
        }

        public function new_property($property_title, $property_address, $property_description, $property_rent, $property_reference, $property_image)
        {
           try
           {
               //PDO statement that uses 'this' (the current user) to create a new user based on entered values
               $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO property (property_title, property_address, property_description, property_rent, property_reference, property_image) 
                                                        VALUES(:title, :address, :description, :rent, :reference, :name)");

               $stmt->bindparam     (":title"   , $property_title);
               $stmt->bindparam     (":address" , $property_address);   
               $stmt->bindparam     (":description" , $property_description);  
               $stmt->bindparam     (":rent"    , $property_rent);  
               $stmt->bindparam     (":reference"   , $property_reference);  
               $stmt->bindparam     (":image"   , $property_image);  
               $stmt->execute(); 
               return $stmt; 
           }
           catch(PDOException $e)
           {
               echo $e->getMessage();
           }    
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look at your prepared statement, `... , :name)");`, it should be `, :image)");`

Comment: As Rajdeep said your value placeholders do not match your bindparam values.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that, thanks guys! I still have the issue of Notice: Undefined index: image in E:\xampp\htdocs\authTest\adminNewProperty.php on line 5 before submitting the form though. And for some reason, the title, address and rent fields are not being sent to the database? they just come up as 0's in there, but everything else is fine

Comment: @Aaranihlus That's because `$_FILES` array is empty when you first load the page, do a `isset()` check first or make use `is_uploaded_file()` function before proceeding. BTW, is `bindparam()` your custom method? Because if it's not, it should be `->bindParam`